# Elasticsearch only shows the _grokparsefailure record, where are the matched ones?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

At the beginning, my pattern is not correct, so every record is unmatched and shown in elasticsearch as a whole line instead of separated rows. 
Then I changed my pattern which passes the http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/. Now I can not see any of my new records in elasticsearch. My elasticsearch only shows the "_grokparsefailure" tagged records.

Where are the matched ones? thx

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause -- a configuration problem in logstash. I chose a wrong  type in the output section. I parse the message, assign value to a variable named "type". So "type" has the wrong value.

Comment: type is actually a key word in ElasticSearch